# Trying to learn more about the singer Gin Gillette

Tags: history

Alright, there is a song that I have become obsessed with called ["Train to Satanville" by Gin Gillette](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMERel9J7bQ)

I have been searching high and low to find out any real information about the singer. I found one other song she did called "She'll Never Let Him Go." But beyond that, I can't find a single thing about this woman! Please help if you know anything!

Comment: Nice song... good luck to find her ! Only appears on this disc [Scum of the Earth](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Various-Scum-Of-The-Earth/release/2866010) maybe if you find the LP you will have more info on the cover...

Comment: Everything about Gin Gillette is given [here](https://oldwax.blogspot.com/2021/05/will-real-gin-gillette-please-stand-up.html) ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20210701211652/https://oldwax.blogspot.com/2021/05/will-real-gin-gillette-please-stand-up.html)). See also her [Musicbrainz entry](https://musicbrainz.org/artist/149a887f-82d6-4ff4-8c5d-22ea9a1ac0f1). She's still alive and you can meet her in [Decatur, GA](https://decaturish.com/2018/02/meet-virginia-a-kroger-employee-with-a-country-music-past/).

Answer (score 4):

I found this interesting story about it, but ironically the writer actually did not want to know anything about her! Here is the [interview of DJ Andrew Weatherall](http://www.factmag.com/2011/07/26/on-record-andrew-weatherall).

<sub>Page archive [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170103095022/http://www.factmag.com/2011/07/26/on-record-andrew-weatherall/).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Virginia Carllile -  Where Are You (Tex, 1955)
Virginia Carllile - Tired Of Your Honky-Tonk Love (Tex, 1955)
Gin Gillette - She'll Never Let Him Go (Musikon, 1961)
Gin Gillette - Train To Satanville (Musikon, 1961)
Thumbs Carlyle & Ginny O'Boyle - Indian Girl, Indian Boy (Epic, 1962)
Thumbs Carlyle & Ginny O'Boyle - Now that you're leavin' me (Epic, 1962)

all 'Gin Gillette" plus photo here [image]

Comment: Source: https://oldwax.blogspot.com/2021/05/will-real-gin-gillette-please-stand-up.html

Answer (score 0):

I think Gin Gillette is actually Robie Lester who did Disney Records in the 60s. If you [look at the 45](https://www.discogs.com/Gin-Gillette-Shell-Never-Let-Him-Go-Train-To-Satanville/release/6367657) she is part of the production.

Comment: No, [her actual name](https://musicbrainz.org/artist/149a887f-82d6-4ff4-8c5d-22ea9a1ac0f1) is Virginia Carllile, born Virginia Boyle (near Gillette, WY).

Answer (score -1):

Some striking similarities with a record credited to Nancy And The Millionaires, called "Atooka, Okla.", featuring one Nancy Zoppi. You Tube link

. The Gin Gillette record is said to be from 1961, the Nancy & Co year of release was 1966, according to Discogs. So far, no direct connection can be extracted from what little info is available. Therefore , this assumption is speculative.

Comment: The voice is only slightly similar. If you wanted to claim they're the same person you'd need a lot more evidence.